# How many times is the Amidah said in a year?

Tags: tefilla, number, shemoneh-esrei

The Amidah is said three times a day during weekdays, four on Shabbat, and I believe a fifth time during Yom Kippur.   Plus there are the repetitions of the Amidah that are said by the Chazen.

For an observant Jew, how many times would that person say or hear the Amidah in a single year?

Comment: You are assuming that the person goes to synagogue for every prayer service? Even then, I'm not sure that there can be a single number as the number of days of Rosh Chodesh for certain months changes from year to year, and as there is a 4th Amida on Rosh chodesh, the addition of a day would change the count for that year. Also, you would have to say if you mean in Israel or not.

Comment: Even if there is not a single number, I would be interested in knowing the range of times that this prayer is said.   The sheer number (which I suspect is well over 1000 is itself remarkable.

Comment: another variable would be leap years -- more weeks means more shabbatot

Comment: @elliot if you just want a quick estimate, then ~5.25 average times per day (counting repetition) for about 370 days is about 2k.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Elliott and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a 385 day maleh leap year in Diaspora and no Torah portions doubled which would yield 54 Shabbatot.

Every day of the year has, Ma'ariv, Shacahrit and Mincha. Including both silent & repetitions you get 5 Amidot per day.

385 * 5 = 1,1925

Add an extra 2 for the days of Musaph:
54 Shabbatot + 20 days Rosh Hodesh + 22 Yom Tov = 96 days * 2 Amidot = 192

- Ne'ilah = another 2

Total 1,925 + 192 + 2 =  2,119.
However, within this count, 2 of the Shabbatot occur during a Yom Tov, and I've included that in the Yom Tov count, so, I'm subtracting 2 Musaphim.

So, your total is 2,117. If I have calculated incorrectly, please update.

This is for a year with such configuration and only in Diaspora. In Israel, the count is less, regular years would be at least 30 days less (depends on year type), and of course, the *kevi'ah* will influence how many Shabatot there are in the year.

(DoubleAA wasn't that far off!)

Comment: Are you double counting Rosh Chodesh and Rosh Hashannah?

Comment: @Silver I did this in Excel, and I'm viewing it now. I listed all the months starting from Cheshvan, not Tishre. So, in short, no.

Comment: what about Shabbos Rosh Chodesh?

Comment: Why do you double-count Mussaf and Neilah?

Comment: @DonielF I don't think I double counted. I added an extra 2 for Neilah only. That is an extra 2 Amidot that occur only on Yom Kippur.

Comment: @Silver - Yes, I guess I did double count Shabbat Rosh Hodesh, here. I have to check a calendar for that *kevi'a* to see how often that occurs. It's probably twice. I'll try to edit, later.

Comment: @DanF “96 days * 2 amidos” - why times 2?

Comment: @DonielF OP wanted me to include both silent and repetition Amidot. This is why I said that each day, there are 5 total - Ma'ariv 1 (no rep.); Shacharit & Mincha 2 (silent & rep.) Hence on days of Musaph, add another 2. On Yom Kippur, Ne'ilah adds an additional 2. Makes sense? I've updated the math, BTW.

Comment: “However, within this count, 2 of the Shabbatot occur during a Yom Tov, and I've included that in the Yom Tov count, so, I'm subtracting 2 Musaphim.

So, your total is 2,117”. The total should be 2,115. If you subtract two musaphim, that’s two silent and two repetitions

Comment: And what if Rosh Hashana, Yom Kippur, or Shavuos are on shabbos?

Comment: @Loani and others - thanks for the mathematical comments, corrections, suggestions, etc. I tried to simplify things in my calculations, above, as there is just one possible *kevi'ah* that fits the above description - a 385 day with 54 regular Shabbat readings that do not coincide with Yom Tov. In such a situation, Pesach begins on Sunday, which, means that Rosh Hashanna, Yom Kippur, and Shavuot all occur on weekdays. I have already accounted for the one Shabbat for each of Pesach and Succot in the counting. I know that I still need to make some other minor math adjustments.

Comment: @DanF, what about my first comment?